# Using Azure B2C with MVC, .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core-3.1

Could anyone provide some insight or new links on using Azure B2C with MVC, .NET Core 3.1. Most examples are based on Core 2.2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/an-aspnet-core-web-app-with-azure-ad-b2c/

However, it seems more than a few things are done differently with 3.1.

The error I encounter in 2.2 is:

> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString')
>      at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI.AzureADB2COpenIdConnectOptionsConfiguration.BuildAuthority(AzureADB2COptions AzureADB2COptions)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI.AzureADB2COpenIdConnectOptionsConfiguration.Configure(String name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.b__0()
>      at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
>      at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
>      at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
>      at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Comment: Have you referred to the sample : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-5-B2C?

Comment: Besides, could you please tell me your error?

Comment: I tried the github sample you cited above, but I could not understand/implement it.

I added exception details/error to original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to configure Azure AD B2C auth for your .net core application, you can use sdk [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI). But please note that you need to choose the right sdk version according to the .net core version you use. For example, if you use .net core 2.2, the sdk version should be 2.2.0.

The detailed steps are as below

1. [Register a web application in Azure AD B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=applications)
2. Implement Azure AD B2C auth in web application

   a. add the following settings in the appsettings.json

   ```
    {
   "AzureAdB2C": {
   "Instance": "https://<your-tenant-name>.b2clogin.com",
   "ClientId": "<web-app-application-id>",
   "Domain": "<your-b2c-domain>"
   "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
   "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_test",
   "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_test2",
   "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_test1"
   },
   ...
   }
   ```

   b. add the following code in the Startup.cs

   ```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
         services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
         {
             // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
             options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
             options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
         });

         services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
             .AddAzureADB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));

         services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
     }

     // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
     public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
     {
         if (env.IsDevelopment())
         {
             app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
         }
         else
         {
             app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
             // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
             app.UseHsts();
         }

         app.UseHttpsRedirection();
         app.UseStaticFiles();
         app.UseCookiePolicy();

         app.UseAuthentication();

         app.UseMvc(routes =>
         {
             routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "default",
                 template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
         });
     }
   ```

   c. Implement sign in and sign out. The sdk has helped us implement sign-in and sign-out method. So we can directly use it. For example

my login.cshtml

```
@using System.Security.Principal
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADB2C.UI
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
@inject IOptionsMonitor<AzureADB2COptions> AzureADB2COptions

@{
    var options = AzureADB2COptions.Get(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}


<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{

            <li class="nav-item">
                <span class="nav-text text-dark">Hello @User.Identity.Name!</span>
            </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="AzureADB2C" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a>
        </li>
}
else
{
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="AzureADB2C" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">Sign in</a>
        </li>
}
</ul>
```

3. Test
   [image]

Comment: That definitely works, but I was trying to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect which should allow me to build my own SessionController. I am trying to better control what page is displayed when the user signs out. Using AzureAdB2C, I am only able to display the View returned from the AzureAdB2C "area". I would like to use the following syntax from another example to sign out: 
    return SignOut(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

Comment: @stephen Is that  when you call your own signout method, you get the above error?

Comment: Jim, good question. When I try to use OpenIdConnect, I encounter the exception cited in the original post as soon as I start the web app.

Comment: @stephen  Could you please provide a simple sample to make me reproduce the issue?

Comment: Just download the project from the original link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/an-aspnet-core-web-app-with-azure-ad-b2c/

and change the framework to .NET Core 3.1. There is a minor issue with ILoggerFactory, but that's easy to get around. After that, what worked fine with my AzureADB2C, does not (HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure).

Comment: @stephen I cannot run the sample. I always get the error HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure. Could you please provide a useful sample.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp/an-aspnet-core-web-app-with-azure-ad-b2c/

runs fine for me "out of the box", it only fails with the same message as you when I switch the project Target Framework to .Net Core 3.1. So, what needs to be changed to make it work?

Comment: @stephen Please refer to the [sample](https://github.com/JimXu199545/NetCoreWeb/tree/master/NetCoreB2C) to know how to implement Azure AD B2C in .net core 3.1