# Azure B2C in Asp.netBoilerplate

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-active-directory, aspnetboilerplate

I am using AspNetBoilerplate template (.NET CORE 3.1). I am trying to add Azure b2c AD authentication
following official help: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-5-B2C

I have successfully implemented above without aspnetBoilerplate template, it works fine. when I try to add this in aspnetboilerplate, it gives me below error on click of Login button.

My View:

```
<form method="get" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login with Microsoft Azure</button>
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Account controller is defined in the Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI NuGet package, in the Area  MicrosoftIdentity.

After associating or adding to the asp.net core 3.1 boiler template , check if the [namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.web.microsoftidentityoptions?view=azure-dotnet) are missed or assembly in dll file is missing  and try to add them and by installing the nuget package .
Or
Check if the configurations associated with the project are  missing by chance and see if namespace can be configured manually.

According to  [signs in/out users - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-sign-in?tabs=aspnetcore#signin-action-of-the-controller)

> In ASP.NET, selecting the Sign-in button in the web app triggers the
> SignIn action on the AccountController controller. In previous
> versions of the ASP.NET core templates, the Account controller was
> embedded with the web app. That's no longer the case because the
> controller is now part of the Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI NuGet package.
> See [AccountController.cs](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI/Areas/MicrosoftIdentity/Controllers/AccountController.cs) for details. This controller also handles the
> Azure AD B2C applications.

Check with below code in configure services method in startup class

```
services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C");

    services.AddControllersWithViews()
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

    services.AddRazorPages();

    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));
}
```

And the below in Configure() in Startup.cs

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
```

Check with the name spaces to be injected in views : [azure ad b2c-asp.net core 3.1](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-developer-community-blog/migrating-azure-ad-b2c-integration-going-from-net-core-3-1-to/ba-p/1983575).

Add the following settings in the appsettings.json

```
{
"AzureAdB2C": {
"Instance": "https://<your-tenant-name>.b2clogin.com",
"ClientId": "<web-app-application-id>",
"Domain": "<your-b2c-domain>"
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
"SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_test",
"ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_test2",
"EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_test1"
},
```

**References:**

1. [ASP.NET MVC 3 - Handling Not Found
   (c-sharpcorner.com)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/asp-net-mvc-3-handling-not-found-with-asp-net-mvc-3)
2. [NetCoreWeb/NetCoreB2C at master |
   (github.com)](https://github.com/JimXu199545/NetCoreWeb/tree/master/NetCoreB2C)
3. [Using Azure B2C with MVC, .NET Core 3.1 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60999720/using-azure-b2c-with-mvc-net-core-3-1)